# java out of range in loop for

Tags: java

This code is working but ugly:

```
for ( int i = 0, l=1; i < word.length() && l < word.length(); i++, l++) {  
    char c = word.charAt(i);
    j = (int) c;
    char nextRank = word.charAt(l);
    k = (int) nextRank;
}
```

I would like to change him to something like that :

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {  
    char c = word.charAt(i);
    j = (int) c;
    char nextRank = word.charAt(i+1);
    k = (int) nextRank;
}
```

This one returns an error: `String index out of range`. I understand why: when it comes to the last letter the "char nextRank = word.charAt(i+1);" has nothing left to do.

But I don't know how to fix this problem!

Comment: If you don't know then who do know?

Answer (score 3):

Start `i` from `1`

```
for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); i++) {  
        char c = word.charAt(i-1);
        j = (int) c;
        char nextRank = word.charAt(i);
        k = (int) nextRank;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Patient:** "It hurts when i do this under that condition"

**Doctor:**  "Well, then if that condition is met, don't do that"

```
if(i+1 < word.length)
{
    char nextRank = word.charAt(i+1);
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int length = word.length() - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    char c = word.charAt(i);
    j = (int) c;
    char nextRank = word.charAt(i + 1);
    k = (int) nextRank;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just decrease the limit of i by 1

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length()-1; i++) {  
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            j = (int) c;
            char nextRank = word.charAt(i+1);
            k = (int) nextRank;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop from 0 to word.length() -1.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {  
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            j = (int) c;
            char nextRank = word.charAt(i+1);
            k = (int) nextRank;
        }
```